# SimpleModal: how to pass mailtolink after Submit in the modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I'm using simple modal to display a legal alert before the user can send email to a specific address:

On my main page:

```
<a href="mailto:somebody@abc.com" class="legalnotice">somebody@abc.com</a>
```

jQuery being used:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.legalnotice').click(function(e) {
        var src = "email_alert.html";
        $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="400" width="390" style="border:0" id="legalFRAME">', {
            closeHTML:"",
            closeCLASS:"simplemodal-close",
            containerCss:{
            backgroundColor:"#f8f8f8",
            borderColor:"#f8f8f8",
            height:500,
            padding:0,
            width:400
        },
        overlayClose: true
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

email_alert.html contains:

```
<form name="alertFORM" id="alertFORM" action="">
  <div class="row-box"><input type="checkbox" /><label>I understand and agrees</label></div>
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="modal-close simplemodal-close" id="Submit" value="Close" />
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#alertFORM').submit(function() {
    window.parent.jQuery.modal.close(true);
});
</script>
```

When the user clicks the email address, the window opens as expected.
They check "I understand" to accept the notice, hit "Submit", and the window closes - as expected. However, I can't figure how to get the opening page to go ahead and continue from where it left off so their email client now opens so they can write an email to the selected address.

Little help please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trigger the `mailto` window to open by using:

```
window.location.href = "mailto:email@example.com";
```

Therefore you could just add that after the modal is closed:

```
$('#alertFORM').submit(function() {
    $.modal.close();
    window.location.href = $('.legalnotice').attr('href');
});
```

If you want a dynamic approach that passes the `href` mailto value when the dialog is opened, use:

```
$('.legalnotice').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var mailto = $(this).attr('href');

    $.modal($('#alertFORM'), {
        closeHTML: "",
        closeCLASS: "simplemodal-close",
        containerId: "modal",
        containerCss: {
            backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
            borderColor: "#f8f8f8",
            height: 500,
            padding: 0,
            width: 400
        },
        overlayClose: true,
        onClose: function (dialog) {
            $.modal.close();
            window.location.href = mailto;
        }
    });
});
```

Within the `onClose` callback, trigger the `mailto` window to open with `window.location.href = mailto` when the dialog is closed:

```
onClose: function (dialog) {
    $.modal.close();
    window.location.href = mailto;
}
```

.. and for your `iframe`:

```
$('.legalnotice').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = "email_alert.html";
    var mailto = $(this).attr('href');

    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="400" width="390" style="border:0" id="legalFRAME">', {
        closeHTML: "",
        closeCLASS: "simplemodal-close",
        containerId: "modal",
        containerCss: {
            backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
            borderColor: "#f8f8f8",
            height: 500,
            padding: 0,
            width: 400
        },
        overlayClose: true,
        onClose: function (dialog) {
            $.modal.close();
            window.location.href = mailto;
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Let me work with that a bit and see where I get. The mailto links are dynamic, and depending on page content, there could be a huge list of addresses on a single page ... so I need to work on passing the email address value to the modal window - correct? (Not asking for code - just want to be sure I'm putting my efforts into the correct direction!)

Comment: Actually, that doesn't seem to work.          

$('#alertFORM').submit(function() {
    window.parent.jQuery.modal.close(true);
 window.location.href = $('.legalnotice').attr('href');
});
         
Console is showing   

Error: TypeError: window.location is null

Comment: @user3173655 The error you were seeing was a result of `window.parent.jQuery.modal.close(true);`... you should use `$.modal.close();` instead. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation to get the iframe with the external file back in there, and it works a treat.

```
$('.legalnotice').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = "email_alert.html";
    var mailto = $(this).attr('href');

    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="400" width="390" style="border:0" id="legalFRAME">', {
        closeHTML: "",
        closeCLASS: "simplemodal-close",
        containerId: "modal",
        containerCss: {
            backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
            borderColor: "#f8f8f8",
            height: 500,
            padding: 0,
            width: 400
        },
        overlayClose: true,
        onClose: function (dialog) {
            $.modal.close();
            window.location.href = mailto;
        }
    });
 });
});
```

Thanks for the assistance!!